# How can to set validation (org.hibernate.validator.constraints) for rest in spring boot project?

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I have project with spring boot, spring mvc and hibarnate, and I want validate rest params, I have controller:

```
import domain.User;
import service.UserService;
import validate.Email;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Boolean registration(@NotEmpty @FormParam("login") String login,
                                @NotEmpty @FormParam("password") String password,
                                @Email(canBeNullOrEmpty = true) @FormParam("email") String email) {
        logger.debug("method registration with params login = " + login
                + ", password = " + password + ", email = " + email);
        return !userService.findByLoginAndPassword(login, password)
                && userService.addUser(new User(login, password, email));
    }

}
```

and my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.8.RELEASE")
    }
}

ext {
    springVersion = '4.1.5.RELEASE'
    jacksonVersion = '2.5.3'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion"

    compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'

    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'

    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVersion"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion"

}
```

so, I wrote registration for my user, and added validation (@NotEmpty for login and password, @Email) for rest params, but validation does not performed :(, I send request with invalid param password="" and request runs without errors :(, Why? I set validation @NotEmpty for password and if I set password="" or null I must see error! becouse set validation. Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is not performed on method parameters. Just move those to a POJO that you annotate with `@Valid` and `@ModelAttributes` and you'll be fine.

Something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Boolean registration(@Valid FooBar fooBar) {
}

static class FooBar {

  @NotEmpty
  String login;

  @NotEmpty
  String password;

  @Email(canBeNullOrEmpty = true)
  String email;

  // getter & setter

}
```

Comment: Does just annotating the parameters with `@Valid` not work, instead of moving the parameters to a POJO? Just to confirm, because I feel to be hazily recalling that we had used @Valid this way in some project.

Comment: You can put `@Valid` on method parameters of course (that's what triggers the validation!). But you can't put constraints on method parameters (so you can't put `@NotNull` for instance).  I'll edit my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Probably I'm wrongly recalling having put constraints on method parameters, then.

Comment: if I want to transfer variables in Form (@FormParam("password") String password) - how can to do it in Form?